# How the numbers(0-9) are prevented from using as variables in JAVA?

Tags: java, variables, numbers

In JAVA(and in every programming language ever invented), we can not use numbers as variables.

So, I was wondering how the 'Java language' developers achieved this. As I see, the only way to achieve this is that somewhere it is declared that a variable name can not be solely numbers.

Can we see the code where it is done so? Or, are the numbers like 1,2,3.. declared as 'static final' somewhere in the basic functionality of java programming language?

I know I risk myself sound stupid by asking this question. But, please let me know your thoughts about this.

Comment: Read books, start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29

Comment: Sure, will do! Thanks for the link, Kan!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is enforced by the compiler.

As part of [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and parsing of the source code, if an something that should be an identifier is composed of digits only, it will get rejected and the compiler will issue a warning.

You will need the compiler source code in order to see how this is done. You can get it one compiler from the OpenJDK project, [here](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/) (thanks to the answer from Brian Agnew).

Comment: Thanks Oded. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the compiler source code is available as part of the OpenJDK project, and can be downloaded via [this page](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/).

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Oded's great answer, [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/syntax.doc.html)'s the C's grammar (which is not that different from Java, in the relevant respects). Variable names need to be an [`identifier`](http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/samples/c.syntax.html#identifier), while an integer has to be an [`integer_constant`](http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/samples/c.syntax.html#integer_constant). Note how an `identifier` cannot start with a digit, while an `integer_constant` has to.

Comment: Thanks for the links. It makes perfect sense now.